# Help with PHP Select Query: WHERE x=y AND a=b AND IF (c != d) Possible?

Tags: php, mysql, select, phpquery

Ok, here we go... I have a select query accessing a **very** abstract database.  My current query looks through 5 tables (using 6 "AND"'s to do it... not fun) and returns whatever records match all criteria, as it should.

My question is this: Can I add something to my current query that basically says "If a record matches all of these, **but** does NOT match all of *these*".

**Example:**

My current query:

```
$query = "SELECT s.state_name FROM `tbl_records` r, `tbl_states` s,
 `tbl_events` e, `tbl_fields` f, `tbl_field_values` v 
WHERE s.state_id = r.state_id AND f.field_id = '$field_id' AND 
v.field_id = f.field_id AND v.event_id = e.event_id AND e.record_id = r.record_id
 AND v.value_id = '$field_value' AND v.is_latest = '1'";
```

Ugly and long, right? Well that gives me all records that match **one** criteria (the record matches a $field_id and $field_value).

Now I need to take all the records this query finds, but subtract any record that meets another criteria, something like " `AND (v.event_id = e.event_id AND f.field_id = '155' AND v.value_id != '1');`

That's the long and ugly version.  **To Summarize:**

I need to create a query that's something like:
    `Select "s.state_name FROM a,b,c,d WHERE (a.1 = b.2 AND c.3 = d.4 *etc*) AND ONLY IF (a.2 = b.3 AND c.4 != d.5)"`

Is this possible? Can you create query that says "If matches all this AND does NOT match all this"?

Let me know if anyone needs more clarification... Which wouldn't surprise me.  Thank you all.

**UPDATE::**  Adding an image to try and clarify what I need.

[table structure http://www.everythingsirie.com/values.jpg](http://www.everythingsirie.com/values.jpg)

The two values under "need to add" need to pertain to the same record.  So in plan english "For this same record, in the table 'tbl_field_values' if the record has a 'field_id' of '155' AND a field_value of '1', don't include it."

But notice there are now **two** field_id's and value_id's.  This is what has me stumped...

**UPDATE 2::**

I have updated the query using answers from @M42 and @Michael.  However I am still getting the same number of returns with or without the "AND NOT"...

```
$query = "SELECT s.state_name FROM `tbl_records` r
INNER JOIN `tbl_states` s ON s.state_id = r.state_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_events` e ON e.record_id = r.record_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_field_values` v ON v.event_id = e.event_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_fields` f ON v.field_id = f.field_id
WHERE f.field_id = '$field_id'
AND v.value_id = '$field_value'
AND v.is_latest = '1'
AND NOT (v.field_id = '155' AND v.value_id = '1')";
```

I think the issue is that the field_id and value_id I need to **NOT** match are in the same table as the field_id and value_id I **DO** need to match.  Here is a pic showing the field_id of 155 with both a value_id of 1 and 0.

I need to NOT include records that have the value_id of 1, ONLY when the field_id is 155... But at the same time I **AM** trying to select records with field_id=12 and value_id=1...

[table structure http://www.everythingsirie.com/valueid.jpg](http://www.everythingsirie.com/valueid.jpg)

I know this is a mess... Sorry.

Comment: What makes this any different than just adding more `AND` statements in your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: FIRE THE DB ADMIN. Thats where I would start.

Comment: The first query is looking for any records that match one field_id, but I need to subtract records that match a different field_id _as well as_ **not** match another field

Comment: @Caleb, I'm with @Matthew on this. I don't see any difference to your request and adding more `AND` to the statement. Instead of asking the question directly, perhaps you should provide a sample data structure and question that data can answer, such as "how can I get all events in this state?"

Comment: Fair enough. Let me see what I can put together

Comment: How on same record in same table could be two different field_id's?

Comment: because of the abstract nature of the DB, the record has multiple rows all linked by 'record_id' or 'event_id' etc. So one 'event_id' will have 'field_id=12' and the same event_id will have 'field_id=155 and value_id=1'

Comment: Comparing @M42's answer with your query in UPDATE 2, isn't this what you want?: `AND NOT (f.field_id = '155' AND v.value_id  != '1')`

Comment: With or Without the ! and with or without the entire AND NOT, I'm always getting the same number of records.  Also, since I don't want records with a value_id of 1, I figured I need to say "NOT records with value_id = 1" Is that the wrong syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as understand, you can add to your query :

```
AND NOT (f.field_id = '155' AND v.value_id != '1')
```

Comment: For some reason this is still giving me the same number of returns.  With or without this addition I am still getting all records returned.  This looks like the right thing to do, but I may be using it incorrectly in this situation...

Comment: Ok.  So I found a way to do it combining answers from both @Michael and @M42.

I ended up getting it by using `AND NOT EXISTS` with a full `SELECT` query inside of it, like this:

    `AND NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_field_values v
    INNER JOIN tbl_events e ON v.event_id = e.event_id
    WHERE e.record_id = r.record_id
    AND v.is_latest = 1
    AND (v.field_id = 155 AND v.value_id = 1)
    )";`


This was doozy for me and I couldn't have done it without everyone's help. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use INNER JOINs to join the tables instead.  They do the same thing as joining the tables with WHERE clauses, but looks nicer IMHO...it doesn't clutter up your WHERE clause.

```
SELECT s.state_name FROM `tbl_records` r
INNER JOIN `tbl_states` s ON s.state_id = r.state_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_events` e ON e.record_id = r.record_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_field_values` v ON v.event_id = e.event_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_fields` f ON v.field_id = f.field_id
WHERE f.field_id = '$field_id'
AND v.value_id = '$field_value'
AND v.is_latest = '1'
```

Comment: This is _very_ helpful to keep things clean and more manageable.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here for update 2:

```
SELECT s.state_name
FROM `tbl_records` r
  INNER JOIN `tbl_states` s ON s.state_id = r.state_id
  INNER JOIN `tbl_events` e ON e.record_id = r.record_id
  INNER JOIN `tbl_field_values` v ON v.event_id = e.event_id
  INNER JOIN `tbl_fields` f ON v.field_id = f.field_id
WHERE ((f.field_id = '12' AND v.value_id = '1')
  OR (v.field_id = '155' AND v.value_id != '1'))
  AND v.is_latest = '1'
```